# MEF and serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, mef

I'm new to [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) and wondering whats the right way to put it together for my setup, since all the basic tutorials I've read don't cover the aspcet of serialization.

I've got a system that consists of modules (all deriving from a common base type `B`). During runtime modules get created (= picked out of a list of types and sent to `Activator`) and removed dynamically (by user input). The instances of those modules are stored in a list structure (`List<B>`) and the module types are all serializable. So to persist/retrieve the state of the modules, this list simply gets serialized/deserialized.

What I want to do now, is to pack the different kinds of modules in different assemblies to allow better extensibility. However, the deserialization of "unknown types" (thereby meaning types of assemblies discovered by MEF) does not seem to work. So I thought of a solution that works like this; assume an API-interface that wraps the module-creation:

```
interface IModulePlugin {
    string FullyQualifiedName {get; }
    Type ModuleType {get; }

    B GetInstance();         // create new instance (Activator)
    B GetInstance(Stream s); // recreate instance by deserialization        

    Stream Serialize();
}
```

Now after import...

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IModulePlugin))]
List<IModulePlugin> plugins;
```

...register the (unambigious) name and module types with the list elements in e.g. a dictionary, so that the name can be stored together with the data of the module during serialization.

The process of deserialization then would become something like this:

- read the name and try to retrieve the corresponding plugin
- call `GetInstance()` against the plugin with the data to deserialize
- ...

Is this the way to do it? Seems a bit complicated in my eyes and I'm not sure this will actually work. The idea was to put the knowledge needed for serialization out to the modules / plugins. However it gets even more complex if the plugins have to depend on each other (like a 'core' plugin and a 'core-extension' one) or versioning comes into place.

(btw: I'm using C# 5 on .NET 4.5 and the BinaryFormatter)

Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

i would comment, but i don't have enough reputation. Seeing that your question is from last year ... i wonder what solutions you found and what solution you had chosen.

Edit: Maybe this will help someone.

What i did is : get a list of Types that i want to save from the MEF components and save them via  System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.
It has a Knowntypes Property that you can set in the constructor.

```
MEF_ComponenentList.Select(item => item.GetType());

public static void SerializeSomething<T>(T objToSave, string fileToSaveTo, IEnumerable<Type> KnownTypes = null)
    {
        var ser = new  System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileToSaveTo);
        if (KnownTypes != null)
        {
            var sum = ser.KnownTypes.Concat(KnownTypes);
            ser = new  System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), sum);
        }
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileToSaveTo, settings))
        {
            ser.WriteObject(writer, objToSave);
        }
    }
```

You have to be carefull with properties you make public etc ... Or you have to use IgnoreDataMember.